# how to add multiple style values in attribute in drupal form

Tags: forms, 6

I have form element like as follows :

```
$form['precio'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Price'),
  '#default_value' => $precio,
  '#size' => 20,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'style'=>'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAEAEA;'
  ),
  '#description' => t('Change the price'),
);
```

how i add more style attributes to 'precio' ?

Comment: Why don't you add a class or id  and do the rest in css?

Comment: if this works: 'style'=>'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAEAEA;' then surely this will also work: 'style'=>'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAEAEA;color:black;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the style attributes as follows :

```
$form['precio'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Price'),
  '#default_value' => $precio,
  '#size' => 20,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'style'=>'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAEAEA;
              margin: 0 3 4;
              color:red;'
  ),
  '#description' => t('Change the price'),
);
```